# os timezone change tomcat need restart

Tags: java, datetime, tomcat

My web application running on Apache Tomcat 7.0. We are calling java util calendar to get the server date-time. The problem is, if the system timezone is changed, the java calendar keeps running with the date-time of the "old" timezone.

JDK used by Tomcat is - JDk1.6

Could you please tell us why tomcat need restart to reflect new timezone?

Comment: Similar to: [*Java 1.7 change in daylight savings is not recognized*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29383690/642706)

Comment: Similar to: [*Handle Daylight Saving in Tomcat without server restart*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49113219/642706)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is always specify the time zone when you use dates in Java. Or specify in tomcat with

> -Duser.timezone=GMT

parameter. Other way Tomcat with load the timezone from the system on start.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Work in UTC whenever possible.

```
Instant.now()  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Never depend on current default time zone setting of your host OS, your JVM, or your database. Specify desired/expected time zone explicitly.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

## Never depend on server’s time zone setting

The real problem is that you have code depending on an aspect over which you have no control and which can be changed at any moment: The JVM’s current default time zone.

You should never write code that depends on the system's default time zone.  Instead, always specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an optional argument passed to relevant classes.

> The problem is, if the system timezone is changed, the java calendar keeps running with the date-time of the "old" timezone.

The host operating system (OS) has its own current default time zone setting and its own time zone definition ([`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)). Ditto for your database server; if sophisticated in date-time handling such as Postgres, it may have its own `tzdata` internally stored. And your JVM too has its own current default time zone setting and its own time zone definition ([`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)). When the definition changes for time zones of interest, you should update the `tzdata` in all three places, either by a software product version update or by a tzdata-specific updater.

All JVM implementations I know of default on launch to setting its own current default time zone to that of the host OS. **After JVM launch, changing the host OS time zone setting should have no effect on your JVM**, at least not in the Oracle and OpenJDK implementations I have seen.

> We are calling java util calendar to get the server date-time.

Never use the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`. These have been entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

> Could you please tell us why tomcat need restart to reflect new timezone?

I would guess that your web app is inappropriately caching an offset-from-UTC rather than always using a time zone. An offset-from-UTC is just a number of hours-minutes-seconds of displacement from UTC. A time zone is much more, a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. So always use a time zone rather than a mere offset. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49120528/642706) to a similar Question for much more detail.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

## UTC

Generally best to always work in UTC unless a zone is required by your business logic or by your user-interface. You should learn to think, work, log, store, and exchange data in UTC. Forget about your own parochial time zone while at work as a programmer or admin.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason for the need to restart is that nobody is catering for servers that travel through different timezones while they're actively running and connected to the internet. Interesting usecase. Obviously rare. Very rare.

Set your server to be on UTC, start tomcat with UTC, then configure your application to format the time in whatever timezone you happen to be interested in in the moment - problem solved.